# Libgdx ParallaxScrolling and TiledMaps

Tags: java, libgdx

I implemented ParallaxScrolling for my SideScroller project, everything is working but the tiled map (the most important part!). I've been trying out everything but it doesn't work (see the code below).

I'm using  ParallaxCamera from GdxTests, it's working perfectly for the background layers.

I can't explain myself properly in english, so I recorded 2 videos:

[Before parallaxScrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mx80kum1mvz2ja/2013-07-02%2013.50.53.mp4)

[After parallaxScrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h31ggxxvvuqfeh/2013-07-02%2013.48.27.mp4)

As you can see, now the platforms appear in the middle of the Y-axis.

I've got a Map class with 2 tiled maps, so I need two renderers too:

```
private TiledMapRenderer renderer1;
private TiledMapRenderer renderer2;



public void update(GameCamera camera) {
renderer1.setView(camera.calculateParallaxMatrix(1f, 0f), camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth / 2, 
           **camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2**, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
renderer2.setView(camera.calculateParallaxMatrix(1f, 0f), camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth / 2,
           **camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2**, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
}
```

In bold, the code I think I should change. I've tried changing parameters, even adding hardcoded values, etc, but one of two: 
1. Nothing happens.
2. Platforms disappear.

Here is some aditional code. The render method:

```
     world.update(delta);
    parallaxBackground.update(camera);

    clear(0.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f, 1);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.calculateParallaxMatrix(0, 0));
    batch.disableBlending();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, -(int)background.getRegionWidth()/2, -(int)background.getRegionHeight()/2);
    batch.end();
    batch.enableBlending();

    parallaxBackground.draw(batch, camera);
    renderer.render(batch);
```

Comment: Just to clarify the issue, after you implemented parallax scrolling, the platforms are now drawing too high up on the screen? I'm not sure why the y values should change at all when implementing scrolling on the x axis. Why not just set the y axis camera view to the same as it was before implementing parallax scrolling?

Comment: Hi. I did it, but it doesn't work. I recorded a video so you can see how I change values: http://www.screenr.com/OfxH